# Im getting a error response from daemon: saying Container isnt running

Tags: postgresql, docker

C:\Users\name>docker run --name demo-postgres -e POSTGRES-PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:alpine
Unable to find image 'postgres:alpine' locally
alpine: Pulling from library/postgres
df20fa9351a1: Pull complete
600cd4e17445: Pull complete
04c8eedc9a76: Pull complete
bf617408977a: Pull complete
639a7724a714: Pull complete
4f160ac5de1c: Pull complete
e568c8257249: Pull complete
a4fe2f495276: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bd975ce4ddb0cf271a3c0132afaa16894ccdbadd0a1e81aa5d1b12727bb43779
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:alpine
81bcca669d820a03e6251517d6f1dcda3731a4f5b95461cd691aca6d4238c5a5

C:\Users\name>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

C:\Users\name>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

C:\Users\name>docker exec -it demo-postgres /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 81bcca669d820a03e6251517d6f1dcda3731a4f5b95461cd691aca6d4238c5a5 is not running

Comment: `docker ps`  and check any logs before you get a bash?

Comment: that what im getting it empty but if I run it again is says I created the container but its not showing in docker ps

Comment: I ran docker logs demo-postgres

Comment: I got this Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

Comment: Notice that flag you are using is > `POSTGRES-PASSWORD` not `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, have you try to change it?

Comment: thanks Ill try that now

Comment: no still having an issue

Comment: Thanks it's working I just docker rm demo-postgres and  recreated it and now it is working